# iPhone XS - face id will be available when iPhone cools down

Tags: iphone, temperature, face-id

I upgraded iOs to 12.4 yesterday on my iPhone XS and am  having problem with Face ID since then. There is no other temperature warning. Only Face Id seems to be having problems. Have tried restarting, restoring but in vain. Any ideas how I can resolve this problem?[image]

Comment: When did you get this phone? Are you charging while trying this? Sometimes the phone gets warm when charging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant access to the camera on iPhone 6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366544/cant-access-to-the-camera-on-iphone-6)

Comment: If you know temperature isn't the issue (eg: you're inside A/C, not charging, and the phone doesn't *feel* warm to the touch), the issue is most likely a malfunctioning sensor. Could be due to water damage, but regardless, I would take it in to an Apple Store to get replaced.